# Ways to generate "parallel" data objects code from single source?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, semantics, semantic-markup

I have a bunch of entities that reflect data flow in my application. Same data goes like this:
1. fluent nHibernate mapping
2. Database Access Object
3. Entity (something like "clean data on server side")
4. DTO object, that is Entity plus maybe some additional fields, used for client-server interaction.

These all must support same set of fields aand I also must have Automapper mappings set up between DAO and Entity and DTO and Entity. As you see it's a lot of manual copypaste. Is there any software to aid in automatic generation of many similar objects from list of fields ?

I use C#.

Answer (score 0):

If there are truly a bunch of common properties between each of the layers, you can put them on a common denominator base type that will be extended by each object in the flow.

If, on the other hand, each layer will be slightly but predictably different, consider writing a LinqPad script to generate the needed code for the other three layers based on one of the layers. LinqPad is a good choice for this kind of work because you don't have to deal with parsing; you can simply use reflection to examine a compiled assembly containing one of the layers when generating the others.

Ultimately, though, I would recommend trying to reduce the number of layers you're dealing with. For example, for layer (4) can you simply "add" the additionaly properties using containment instead of copy paste? For example:

```
public class CustomerDto { 
    public CustomeEntity Entity { get; set; } 
    public int SomeProp { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not too familiar with NHibernate, but do you really need different types for (1) and (2)?

Another way to approach things is to focus on the data that individual features need to work with rather than creating a whole host of classes for each "table" in the database. That way, you can write a LINQ query to go straight from the data into the type you'll actually use.

Adding layers to an application often seems nice in theory, but in practice I've found that it often fails to provide much abstraction while adding a lot of coding overhead.